# How to get the Drive path mentioned in properties file in to File

Tags: java, spring, file

where i have to read and write userdata.properties from UI, every thing up to now is working like reading and writing ,before i mention the hardcoded direct path in file like this

```
File f = new File("D:\\user\\userdata.properties")
```

but my problem is if i mention like this i cannot change the path,for that i have to mention 
D:\user\userdata.properties in another path.properties file ,now i have to read path.properties file in

```
File f = new File(........)
```

please help me how o do that.this is how presently i am using to read userdata.properties

```
@RequestMapping("/proxy")
    public String ProxySettings(Model model) throws Exception {



        File f = new File("D:\\sahi\\userdata.properties");
        //String path = MobeeProxyChangeController.class.getResourceAsStream("/property/path.properties").toString();


        Properties properties = new Properties();

        try {
            properties.load(new FileInputStream(f));

            String getHost = properties.getProperty("ext.http.proxy.host");
            String getPort = properties.getProperty("ext.http.proxy.port");

            model.addAttribute("proxyHost", getHost.trim());
            model.addAttribute("proxyPort", getPort.trim());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "proxyFile";

    }
```

Thanks in advance

venu

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't call the `load` method for each request. That will turn out very expensive for you.

Secondly, since you're already using spring, there is no need to read a properties file this way. You can just inject it.

I suggest creating fields for `proxyHost` and `proxyPort` in your class as fields.

```
public class MyController {
    ...
    private String proxyHost;
    private String proxyPort;

    @RequestMapping("/proxy")
    public String ProxySettings(Model model) throws Exception {
        model.addAttribute("proxyHost", this.proxyHost);
        model.addAttribute("proxyPort", this.proxyPort);

        return "proxyFile";
    }

    // provide setters for the above fields or use @Autowired
}
```

Your spring configuration would look like:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:userdate.properties" />
</bean>

<bean class="com.foo.MyController">
    <property name="proxyHost" value="${ext.http.proxy.host}"/>
    <property name="proxyPort" value="${ext.http.proxy.port}"/>
</bean>
```

You can read the `userdata.properties` either from the classpath or file system depending on where you keep it.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply,so should i mention like how we mention to read database.properties applicationContext.xml file

Comment: actually i should not mention userdata.propeties in my project,that is external file inside my D: drive ,i should only read and write IP and Port inside userdata.properties through UI .

Comment: What do you mean? You contradict your first and second sentences. How can you "read and write" by not reading?

Comment: In Ui when i click on change proxy it will read the data from a properties file.so when i change the values and submit it will write that changed data into file.File f = new File("D:\\sahi\\userdata.properties");
  Properties properties = new Properties();

  properties.load(new FileInputStream(f));
  OutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(f);String httpHost = request.getParameter("proxyHost");
   String httpPort = request.getParameter("proxyPort");properties.setProperty("ext.http.proxy.host", httpHost.trim());
    properties.setProperty("ext.http.proxy.port", httpPort.trim());

Comment: sir please don't mine i am in little bit confusion

Answer (score 0):

Put your properties file on the classpath and reference it via a `MessageSource`

Example:

Properties file "foo.properties":

```
foo=bar
baz=phleem
```

Java code:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("foo");
    System.out.println(messageSource.getMessage("foo", new Object[0], Locale.getDefault()));
}
```

Output:

> bar

You can let Spring inject that `MessageSource`, but I think you have to do that through XML (or through `@Configuration`). But you can also do it manually, however, you should only do it once per class, not once per request.

---

OK, here's an example of how you could wire it together using Spring:

XML configuration:

```
<bean id="proxySettings" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="userdata" />
</bean>
```

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class ProxyController {

    private static final Locale LOCALE = Locale.getDefault();
    private static final Object[] EMPTY_ARGS = new Object[0];

    @Autowired @Qualifier("proxySettings")
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @RequestMapping("/proxy")
    public String proxySettings(final Model model) throws Exception {
        model.addAttribute("proxyHost", messageSource.getMessage("ext.http.proxy.host", EMPTY_ARGS, LOCALE));
        model.addAttribute("proxyPort", messageSource.getMessage("ext.http.proxy.port", EMPTY_ARGS, LOCALE));
        return "proxyFile";
    }

}
```

Comment: Sean Patrick Floyd sir first i have read the drive path mentioned in path.properties ,if that reads the path then i have to read key value pair inside that userdata.properties.

Comment: sir is there any other way to solve this mentioning <util:properties..in xml file

Comment: @venu don't you sir me :-). `<util:properties>` defines the properties inline in the XML, that doesn't seem to be what you want

Comment: instead of mentioning directly this D:\\sahi\\userdata.properties in File f = new File("D:\\sahi\\userdata.properties"); ,i have to read it as key from another properties file ,key=D:\\sahi\\userdata.properties then i can read it as File f = new File(key);

Comment: please could you post some example

Comment: Sean Patrick Floyd Thanks for the example code ,i will try to implement that

Comment: so at last i was successful of achieving what i need,by mentioing the drive path also in datasource,and using this in my controller class private @Value("${filename}")String fileDir; ,thanks @Sean patrick Floyd for your help giving me the quick reply,sorry for any trouble

Comment: @venu no trouble, but it would be nice if you accepted the answer